# how do i make an exact duplicate of a flash drive for backup purposes

Tags: usb-drive

I currently have Ubuntu MATE installed (full install) on a flash drive.  How do I make an exact copy of the flash drive for backup purposes?  Because I'm getting scared about the eventual inevitable failure of the drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A complete 1:1 clone/image of any drive or partition can be made with `dd`.

First find out the file descriptor corresponding with the device you want to back up. The command `lsblk` will be useful for that. I will assume now that you want to back up the partition `/dev/sdb1`, please change this value to match your configuration.

Then you can run `dd` like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=~/my-backup.img bs=4M status=progress
```

**Warning!** *Whatever you specify as `of=...` will get overwritten! Make sure you do not accidentally wipe your data and check the correctness of this argument twice!*

Here is what the parameters mean:

- `if=/dev/sdb1`: read from file `/dev/sdb1` (which represents the raw partition)
- `of=~/my-backup.img`: write to the specified file. File name, extension and location is arbitrary, just don't write to the same partition you are reading.
- `bs=4M`: always process blocks of 4 MB at once. This speeds the process up.
- `status=progress` see some progress info while it is running

---

When you later want to restore the image again, simply swap `if=` and `of=` so that the file gets read and you write to a partition (which should have the same size).

Comment: Sorry, i have a stupid question.  So with the filename post "of" I would put something like "of=/home/flashbackup.img".   I assume .img is necessary?

Comment: The `.img` is not necessary, as Linux systems normally don't care about file extensions. It's just for the humans to get a better idea what the file contains. Where you store the image file is arbitrary, just make sure you're not writing it to the same device you're reading from. I would recommend `~/my-backup.img` (`~` stands for `/home/YOUR-USERNAME`).

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left. Also make sure to invest two minutes in taking the [tour] where you can learn the most important things about how this site works. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

1) Either get another one of the **EXACT** same flash drive, or a different flash drive **greater in capacity**.

Note: You could also write it to a `.img` file if you don't care about having a functional backup. (As in, you can boot the backup)

2) Boot from a live DVD, or any other Ubuntu install that's not the USB stick you want to clone

## Disclaimer: I WILL NOT BE RESPONSIBLE FOR YOU BRICKING YOUR COMPUTER BECAUSE YOU FAILED TO SPECIFIY THE CORRECT BLOCK DEVICE!

To identify which is the correct block device, run: `lsblk`.

3) Fire up a terminal and run:

```
#Replace /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc accordingly!!!

sudo dd if="/dev/sdb" of="/dev/sdc" status="progress"
```

4) Wait. For possibly several hours, depending on the size of your USB drive.*

*You can add the `bs=4M` parameter to the end of the `dd` command, which will speed it up exponentially. It may or may not boot though. You could try doing it with the parameter first, and if it didn't work, then without.